# RegEx: how to remove a specific line from content

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm not at all a RegEx expert... But here is what I would like to do:

I have a WordPress website that has recently change his theme. In the Posts content there is some old specific stuff I would like to completly remove.

For removing I'm using this brillant script: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ that can use regular expressions.

What I would like to remove is all that begin by:

```
<p><a class="footrigger foobox"
```

and end with:

```
</p>
```

Example, this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <p><a class="footrigger foobox" href="#foohiddengallery" rel="attachment"><img class="wp-image-27181 size-entry_with_sidebar alignnone" src="https://www.mydomaine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/my-image-863x328.jpg" alt="Aerospace - Albin Quasar" width="863" height="328" /></a></p> Aliquam tincidunt accumsan scelerisque.
```

Should become:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt accumsan scelerisque.
```

Thanks a lot and excuse for my bad english, I'm French...

Answer (score 0):

In the regex section enter:

```
<p><a class="footrigger foobox"(.+?)<\/p>
```

and replace with an empty value.

If you suspect that you have new lines within the text you should also select the "s" option "dot matches also newlines"

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it works :-) Can you please give the whole syntax with the "s" option please ?

Comment: I've added a screenshot :)